# How can a client be a server too?

Tags: python, sockets, server, tcp

Description:
I have just finished a small course about socket and I have an idea to create a trivia game using python. The idea is to let every user to be the host and the client (server and client).
For example 3 devices have the program, one shares wifi creating a local network to whom the other 2 devices with the app connect and the device who shares network is the server for all of them and is the client too.

Code: it's a trivia game where the sever gives the question and the client answers. It's multi clients server. (it's 2 long codes)

Question:
How to I combine them to be in one program code?

additon:
i tried:

```
import client_side
import server_side
from threading import Thread
def main():
    thread = Thread(server_side.main())
    thread.start()
    client_side.main()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()'
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use multiprocessing or multithreading. One process/thread for the server, another for the client.

Comment: Are you sure you need to put them in the same program? You can simply run the server and client from different terminal windows.

Comment: This is one case where multithreading DOES work very well in Python, because the threads spend most of their time blocked waiting for I/O.  If you're going to build something serious, I strongly recommend you look at the Twisted library for Python.  It makes socket stuff fun.

Comment: SO is not really a good place for discussion of general design. You need to ask specific questions about actual code you've written. So try to put this together, and if you can't get it working post a new question.

Comment: @Barmar yes i want them in the same program so every user can be the server for other users and for himself

Comment: TOP - still waiting for help please

Comment: Threading can be used to run the server and client code separately and parallely and and you need to share data among the thread. Also instead you can use multiprocessing if you want to run the client and server programme as separate process.